# When use Google Analytics SDK for Android v2 can not get any crash or Exception,I had try EasyTracker and ExceptionReporter but useless?

Tags: google-analytics

Use EasyTracker:`<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>`

Ues ExceptionReporter:

```
UncaughtExceptionHandler myHandler = new ExceptionReporter(
    myTracker,                                        // Currently used Tracker.
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(),                    // GoogleAnalytics singleton.
    Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler());     // Current default uncaught exception handler.

Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(myHandler); // Make myHandler the new default uncaught exception handler.
```

I can get other data,like event ,page,but I can not get any data of crash and Exception.I have set some `uncatch` exception and `crashs` in my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look in the API doc:

```
ExceptionReporter(Tracker tracker, ServiceManager serviceManager, java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler originalHandler)
```

GoogleAnalytics does not implement the ServiceManager interface.... luckily GAServiceManager does.  Thus if you change:

```
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance()
```

to:

```
GAServiceManager.getInstance()
```

It works for me

Comment: Got the same problem but for me this is not working i am afraid